# Can tritium undergo $\beta^+$ decay and become three free neutrons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Am aware that tritium commonly undergoes $\beta^-$ decay to become helium-3, but is it possible it can undergo $\beta^+$ decay and therefore become three unbound neutrons? If it is possible, over what length of time could we expect half a given mass of tritium to undergo this?

Answer (score 4):

Tritium nucleus (triton) mass is 3.015501 atomic mass units (https://www.accessscience.com/content/triton-nuclear-physics/711000), neutron mass is 1.008665 atomic mass units (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron), thus, 3 neutrons are heavier than one triton, so triton cannot decay into three neutrons.

Comment: Shouldn't the created positron (0.000549 atomic mass units) be considered, too?
But anyway, your reasoning still applies.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch : You can take into account the positron mass, but, as you noticed, the data I provided is sufficient to draw the conclusion.

Comment: What if a triton had some spare kinetic energy, meaning its mass was equivalent to three neutrons via $E = mc^2$?

Comment: @6thNapoleon : It would not change anything: there would still be not enough energy in the frame of reference where the triton nucleus is at rest.